# multi column bar chart excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am working with data from a questioner in two columns that are linked and that I want to display in a bar chart. The first has ages ranging from 18 to 24 and the second has yes no maybe and dont know.

I want to display it in a bar chart with age range on x axis and then have 4 bars for each age which correlate to yes no maybe and dont know. and then the y axis would be the frequency of those. I can't figure out how to format it correctly to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If each row is the pair of answers to two questions ("how old are you" and "what do you think about X") you probably need a quick PivotTable to count the answers, sliced and diced into ages and responses, then chart that. Or go straight to a PivotChart for the same.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in Excel, you'll need to layout your data in a pivot table format.

1. Format your data as a table, with ages in rows and your answer type in columns (or you can switch them, just be consistent).
2. Add a blank clustered column chart (this avoids Excel's habit of guessing what you want).
3. Add your data series.  Each column (answer type) is a series, so choose the column header for your series name, and all of the following rows for your data.
4. Repeat for all four columns.
5. Format as appropriate.

[image: Sample]

Comment: It sounds like the OP does not have aggregated data, so probably needs a PivotTable to get to this format, then your answer works from there.